# C - Is charArray always the same as &charArray?

Tags: c

I am reading [an article about whole program optimization](http://gamearchitect.net/Articles/CompilerOptimizationOfMA2.html). The last paragraph in the Link-Time Code Generation section says zeroing an array allocated on the stack may not have the same effect depending on how it's zeroed:

> Turning on whole program optimization did uncover several bugs that had undefined behavior.  Without WPO, these had somehow not crashed.  With WPO, they did.  In one case, a member function call was being made through a pointer to uninitialized memory.  In several other cases, it was assumed that arrays on the stack were identical to their own addresses.  **That is, it was assumed that memset(&charArray, 0, sizeof(charArray)) would have the same effect as memset(charArray, 0, sizeof(charArray)).  This is not guaranteed by the standard, and appears to change under WPO.**

I thought if I did `char foo[1]` that `foo` would always be `==` to `&foo`. Can someone explain what's happening here? Thanks

Comment: It depends on the variable that was passed as a function argument. In the case of `char array[10]` the function `scanf` for example, will work whether you pass `array` or `&array`. But if the array was obtained dynamically, say `array = malloc(10)` then it matters very much. In that case `array` and `&array` are very different.

Comment: @WeatherVane; No. Compiler will warn against `&array`.

Comment: @haccks presumably you mean in the first case, yes compiler warning, but correct function. In the second case, obviously.

Comment: As we don't know what is the type of `charArray`, the question has no definite answer.

Comment: The real boner with static array vs malloc'ed memory here is `sizeof`.

Comment: @Drop we do, OP says `char foo[1]`

Comment: @WeatherVane But this assumption is not confirmed in the original text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`foo` is an array and in expressions `foo` will converted to pointer to its first element, except when an operand  of unary `&` and `sizeof` operators. So, in such cases `foo == &foo[0]`. `&foo` is the address of array `foo`, not the address of first element of `foo`.
Though the value of `foo` and `&foo` is equivalent, their types are different. `foo` is of type `char *` after decay while `&foo` is of type `char (*)[1]`.

Comment: So you are saying `foo` is really only equivalent to `&foo[0]`?

Comment: How does this apply to the `memset` example and what conclusion should we made? How does it change in presence of LTCG/WPO?

Comment: @newguy; Yes, but after decay as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Drop; Pointer arithmetic with `array` and `&array` would be different. For `char foo[2]`, if `memset(&foo, sizeof(foo), 0)` starts to fill first byte and increment the passed pointer to fill another then it will fill the element next to `foo[1]` instead of it. This memory location is not allocated and writing to un-allocated memory location will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: But why should there be a difference between `memset(foo, 0, sizeof(foo))` and `memset(&foo, 0, sizeof(foo))` (assuming e.g. `char foo[1]`) ? If I understand your answer correctly, both `foo` and `&foo` evaluate to the address of the first element, so `memset()` won't see a difference.

Comment: @MartinR; Quoted text in the question says: *That is, it was assumed that memset(&charArray, 0, sizeof(charArray)) would have the same effect as memset(charArray, 0, sizeof(charArray)). This is not guaranteed by the standard, and appears to change under WPO.* This particular case of `char foo[1]` may work but one can't generalize it.